# Space between words

Tags: typography, terminology

I understand the difference between kerning and tracking, but is there a term for the space between words. For example, I have a document in which the spacing in the line of text is so tight, that it is difficult to read. So, I'd like to increase the space between words for legibility.

Comment: Yes, it's called [word spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_spacing). What software are you using?

Comment: I am looking at a PDF file and I need to tell the publisher to increase the word spacing. Thought there might be a more technical term. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: @ZachSaucier, I don't think it's enough for answer. Feel free to elaborate if you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for adjusting the spacing between WORDS for a font (not letters)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124556/is-there-a-term-for-adjusting-the-spacing-between-words-for-a-font-not-letters)

Answer (score 1):

It's called "word spacing" in most software. Not all text programs offer it, but layout programs typically have min, max, and average settings for word spacing. These are either program-wide, document-wide, or style-level settings. Some may offer it at paragraph level.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually called "tracking" in proper Typography terminology, and "word spacing" for the rest of the world : ). If you tighten it up, words start to jumble on top of each other. Loosen it too much, and you might end up with a text which is difficult to read. What tracking does is modify the sidebearings of all letters in a given text. Sidebearings are the blank space to both the left and right of every glyph in a given font, and it is normally defined by the type designer.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter-spacing