# What is the space between words called in typography (not kerning or tracking)?

Tags: typography

I know what tracking and kerning are I just want to know what the title for the space between words are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a term for adjusting the spacing between WORDS for a font (not letters)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124556/is-there-a-term-for-adjusting-the-spacing-between-words-for-a-font-not-letters)

Answer (score 4):

It is simply called [Word spacing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_spacing).

> Word spacing in typography refers to the size of the space between words. It should be distinguished from letter-spacing (the spacing between the letters within each word) and sentence spacing (the spacing between sentences). Typographers may modify the spacing of letters or words in a body of type to aid readability and copy fit, or for aesthetic effect. In web browsers and standardized digital typography the word spacing is controlled by the CSS1 word-spacing property.

Related, if not a duplicate: [Is there a term for adjusting the spacing between WORDS for a font (not letters)?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/124556/is-there-a-term-for-adjusting-the-spacing-between-words-for-a-font-not-letters)